# Hanging leg curls

Tags: exercise, muscle, training, exercise-technique, legs

Has anyone tried hanging from a bar with a dumbbell between the legs and trying to do leg curls?

For leg/knee raises it works fine, I'm asking cause I don't want to injure myself in the gym while experimenting exercises.

For people who tried it, does the dumbbell between legs work? if not are there better alternatives, like maybe using bands as resistance or using dipping belts with plates...

Edit:

So I tried it by myself,the dumbbell between legs only works with small dumbbells. 10 kilograms at max

With the dipping belt it works fine with the plate behind the back and allows to use the most weight, but it doesn't give any resistance in the bottom part of the exercise and after a while either the grip or the trapezius get too fatigued to keep doing the exercise.

Bands are by far the best as they be placed in different ways and still work, but again has the same limitations of the dipping belt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be honest, I haven't tried it. It sounds very awkward, and you're probably very limited in terms of what kind of weight you can use. Also, you'd be limited by what kind of dumbbells are present in your gym.

Presumably you're attempting to get a good hamstring workout by doing these curls (as that is usually associated with weighted knee flexion).

What I suggest you do instead is a variety of

- glute ham raise
- barbell hip thrust
- bridge curls
- bridge curls with physio ball

(All of these exercises can be googled as written if you need to see what they are or how they're done.)

Importantly, avoid the leg curl machine, as that is one of the lower back killers, because we have a tendency to try and scoot our butt down towards our heels when our hamstrings get fatigued.

If you want some more details on this, these are all tips I took straight from one of the latest Athlean-X videos on Youtube, specifically this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Anl0osYkg8

Note that the title is referring to the damage that can be done by using the leg curl machine wrong, and the video presents alternative hamstring exercises.

Comment: I don't use any machine, too much sitting already through the day. All the exercises I do are done standing,hanging,kneeling or bent over.